# Rust doesn't see my overloaded f64 multiplication operator

Tags: operator-overloading, rust, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I'm implementing a simple matrix library in rust and I'm currently writing the operator for scalar multiplication. Right-multiplication works:

```
impl<T: Num + Zero + Clone + Float> Mul<T, Mat<T>> for Mat<T> {
    fn mul(&self, rhs: &T) -> Mat<T> {
        self.componentwise(|v| v.clone() * *rhs)
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to do left-multiplication, I assumed the following code would do what I want:

```
impl<T: Num + Zero + Clone + Float> Mul<Mat<T>, Mat<T>> for T {
    fn mul(&self, rhs: &Mat<T>) -> Mat<T> {
        rhs.componentwise(|v| *self * v.clone())
    }
}
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
let A = mat![[1f64, 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]];
let P = A * 4f64; // works!
let Q = 4f64 * A; // error...
```

The error is `` error: mismatched types: expected `f64`, found `linalg::Mat<f64>` (expected f64, found struct linalg::Mat) ``. Can I only have f64 * f64 multiplication, or am I approaching the second case wrong? I tried implementing it for f64 specifically with `impl Mul<Mat<f64>, Mat<f64>> for f64`, but that still doesn't work.

I found that I could make it work using `4f64.mul(&A)`, but that is not ideal.

Comment: [Multidispatch](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17669) made it work for the method call syntax, but apparently the operator syntax doesn't do multidispatch properly...

Comment: @FrancisGagné: Given that associated types is still a work in progress as far as I know, I am not too surprised. I believe that it is *expected* to work for 1.0 though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related with the declaration : your seconde impl declration is for `Mult<Mat<T>, Mat<T>>`, so my guess is that it permits to multiply two matrices, which is not what you want.

(I wanted to post a comment, but I cannot do this yet :()

Comment: No, this is incorrect. `Mul` trait is defined like this: `trait Mul<RHS, R>`, that is, the first parameter is the type of the right argument of `*` and the second parameter is the result type. The type of the left argument is `Self`, i.e. the type for which the trait is implemented.

Comment: My bad, sorry for the bad answer.